# Iterating result of Linq query

Tags: asp.net, linq

I am using following code to get result form a dataTable, but while using the resultant query in foreach loop, it throws an exception: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.String'". Please guide me where I have error in code.

```
var query = from detailRow in dtDetail.AsEnumerable() 
group detailRow by detailRow.Field<string>("Domain") into grouping
select new
{
   Domain = grouping.Key,
   Impressions = grouping.Count(),
   Clicks = 
   grouping.Sum(detailRow => int.Parse(detailRow.Field<string>("Clicks").ToString())),
   url = grouping.First<DataRow>()
}; 

foreach (var detailRowGroup in query)
{
  console.wirteline(detailRowGroup.Domain + detailRowGroup.Impressions + detailRowGroup.Clicks + detailRowGroup.url);

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem, and found that I have had two mistakes in my code. Those were;

1. I used String on the place of Int64. By replacing String with Int64 the error resolved.

2. For DBNULL I used if condition.

Following is the code line;

```
Clicks = grouping.Sum(detailRow => Int64.Parse(detailRow.IsNull("Clicks") ? "0" : detailRow.Field<Int64>("Clicks").ToString())),
```

Thanks Steven and Steve Haigh.

Answer (score 1):

Your `dtDetail` `DataTable` contains a column, named `Click` that contains values of type `Int64`, while you are trying to retrieve it as an `String`. The problem is in the following line:

```
int.Parse(detailRow.Field<string>("Clicks").ToString())
```

Change it to:

```
int.Parse(detailRow.Field<Int64>("Clicks").ToString())
```

Comment: Thank you Steven, that was the problem. But now there is an other problem, that is of dbnull values. While system tries to parse a null value it throws exception, don't know how to handle it.

Comment: You can do `detailRow.Field<Int64?>("Clicks")` (thus with the `?`).

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing about your data it is hard to say, but I would guess that your Clicks column is numeric, so you would want the type parameter to be in `long` (64 bit int)?

I.e.

```
detailRow.Field<long>("Clicks")
```

maybe?

If that is true, then you can probably refactor your code to avoid the parsing too.